# Can raspberry pi 2 take more than one input

Tags: gpio, python, real-time

This is basically a followup question to my previous questions (you don't need to read them to answer it). Primary question is, can a Raspberry Pi 2 take more than one inputs from different circuits at the same time (same code running)? I have built a functioning photogate.
Here is my circuit:
[image: my circuit for photogate]

The code that I am using is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO import time     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN)     start = time.time() stop = time.time()
gateState = False     try:
        while True:
            if (GPIO.input(11) != gateState):
                gateState = not gateState                    
                if (gateState == True):
                    start = time.time()    
                else:
                    stop = time.time()
                    if stop - start > 0.0001:
                        print "Time:  ", stop - start, "s"
                        print "Speed: ", 1.5/(stop-start), "m/s"
                        print " " except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

So, I was wondering, how I would use another photogate on the same Pi at the same time as the first position to measure speed of an object at two times. (basically use two photogates). How would I manipulate the code to use two photogates at the same time, that is if Pi can do it.
Which GPIO would I use, (any random two?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave you code in [raspberry pi2 photogate](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38456/raspberry-pi2-photogate) which will work with multiple gates and +/- 10 µs timing.

You should be able to see that the code you posted above can not work with multiple gates.  In an attempt to gain timing resolution the code you posted is using a busy wait.  You can not busy wait in more than one place at the same time.

Comment: I will try this as well in a new sd card (new raspian). I might ask questions about it later. Thanks

Comment: @SarthakGarg You can store many programs on one SD card.

Comment: Multiple GPIO libraries? Because your method said to remove the older GPIO library. Also, i dont want to mess with the things as at least something is working. And I have useless micro SDs lying around so why not!

Comment: @SarthakGarg It says to remove any existing directory called PIGPIO as that will be overwritten by a new install of pigpio.  No mention of other libraries as far as I can see.  There are dozens of Pi GPIO libraries.  The can happily co-exist with each other.

Comment: Ohh, i thought PIGPIO was the library, never mind. I will probably install it as the more the merrirer (in this case). Could you give me some guidance on the above comment in the answer above. (my comment for the above answer- both the arduino one and the accuracy one) Thanks

Comment: pigpio is the name of my library.  Normally it is downloaded and expanded into a directory called PIGPIO where it is built.  It is just safest to start off with a clean installation so I advise removing the old directory before installing a new version.  In your case you wouldn't have a directory called PIGPIO as you have not previously installed the library.

Comment: do you know what is the accuracy of my current photogate

Comment: @SarthakGarg I have a fair idea.  Rather than ask why not test?  Feed in pulses of known duration and record the results.  Do that many times and graph the expected against the actual.  The answer will then be obvious.

Comment: But how will I feed impulses that are accurate to microseconds. I have already tested it with blocking it for a set period but i cant measure the error of something with something that has a greater error?(that is my stopwatch) or even test it with fixed impulses as i can't make the impulses that accurate?

Comment: It depends on the time periods involved, i.e. how long between start trigger and end trigger are you planning to measure , microseconds, milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days?  For anything less than seconds I'd probably use hardware PWM, for anything less than hours I'd probably use pigpio waveforms, for anything longer then that then what you have at the moment may well be accurate enough without the need for formal test.  So how long in time between start and end of photogate?

Comment: I hope to be able to measure accurately to microseconds +-10 but milliseconds would be fine as well. What do you mean by hardware PWM and pigpio waveforms.

Comment: if this is not possible with raspberry alone, could you guide me to a overview of building something that can measure to that accuracy. Thank You

Comment: I have given you code which will measure to +/- 10 microseconds.  I will ask **one last time** - how long between the start trigger and the end trigger.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean but if you mean approximate lenght of actual measurment, then it would approximately be 0.0001-0.01 s. Sorry for any trouble!

Comment: That's quite a bit shorter than I expected.  I would test with the following procedure.  Connect a wire between GPIO 18 (pin 12) and the GPIO you are going to connect to the photogate.  GPIO 18 can send highly precise pulses.  Start PWM pulses on GPIO 18, at say ten pulses per second.  Set the dutycycle so that the off pulse is so many microseconds after the start pulse.  E.g. at 10 Hz each pulse can be at most 100000 µs.  So 100% dutycycle is 100000 µs, 1% would be 100 µs.  Then feed the known length pulses into your program and check what the program outputs.

Comment: pigpio can program the hardware to generate the test pulses.  pigs hp 18 10 500000 starts 50% dutycycle pulses on GPIO 18 at 10 Hz (dutycycle is out of 1000000, a million).

Comment: Could you explain what you said. I am still a highschool student doing this as a personal project/school ia

Comment: Generally part of the software development process is testing (design, code, test - ignoring all the other activities).  To test software you feed in known test data and record the results.  You check the actual results against the expected results to confirm the correct operation of the software.  The job of your software is to accurately time GPIO level changes.  To test the software you need to feed in pulses of a known duration.  You expect the software to accurately measure the length of the pulses.  Hardware PWM is a simple method of generating Pi test pulses of known length.

Comment: is the hardware pulse width modulation a physical object or a software simulated pulse? Also, what do I use to implement it in either case?

Comment: The Pi has two hardware PWM channels (their principal use is to generate audio).  It is a physical thing.  The software configures the setting (i.e. go this fast, this often), but once initialised everything is hardware driven, and it becomes independent of any software under test.

Comment: Going through all this, can't I just use your code as it has accuracy of +-10us? Also,when you say connect a wire between gpio18 and gpio 3 (one i am using), do i need to add a joint into the circuit? Also, what code/program/ anything do i use to send the 100us pulses? and how do i feed it into my code/program?

Comment: If you want simpler maths just send one pulse a second and use the command "pigs hp 18 1 x", where x is the pulse length in microseconds.  The only disadvantage is that it will take longer to perform a test run (I'd run the test a thousand times or so to get decent stats).  Type those commands in from the command line (the pigpio daemon must be running).  I believe pigpio timing will be better than anything else you find on the Pi.  But to be sure of that you need to test the alternatives.  If you don't trust pigpio to start the pulses use the wiringPi gpio command.

Comment: I am sorry if  sound stupid but, exactly what should I do? Do i need to change the circuit someway (add that extra wire going to the GPIO 18)? where do i add that command how how do i make my code pick up that pulse? this might be asking for too much but could you give almost exact directions of what i need to do? As far as I understand: do i set the input in the code to 18 and just put "pigs hp 18 1 x" in terminal? and then run the code. where x is the pulse length in microseconds.

Comment: Removing the wire from the photo gate to GPIO 17 and adding a wire between GPIO 18 and GPIO 17 would be simplest.  Then just enter the pigs hp 18 1 x command in a terminal.  Test pulses will now be fed from GPIO 18 to GPIO 17.  You should not need to alter your software if it is using GPIO 17.  GPIO 17 is on pin 11, GPIO 18 is on pin 12.

Comment: I switched my input to gpio 3, would it work then as well or do i need to change my input to 17?

Comment: GPIO 18 to GPIO 3 (pin 5) is pretty much the same.

Comment: I wll get back to you after trying it!

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it gives me the line: "bash: pigs: command not found." What am I doing wrong. I had replaced x with 100 for 100 mu but everything else was exactly the same. And I ran the program after and before putting that command in the terminal. Still the same result.

Comment: You have not installed [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html).

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I had been busy. So i installed the pigpio and then, when i run that command in lxterminal, nothing happens. It just goes to the next line. My code when i run it after starting that command gives no values. No speed or time. Nothing happens. I have even tried first running the code and then running that command in lxterminal. What am I doing wrong? - @joan

Comment: I suggest you start a new question explaining the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use multiple input circuits driving multiple GPIOs, provided that the voltage range is appropriate and all share a common ground with the pi.

No, this is not a particularly good way to do time measurements, as the pi typically runs a *multistasking operating system* such as Linux (or, if you must, Windows) and that is notorious for resulting in a substantial and variable *latency* in responding to external stimulus.  In theory you could overcome this by doing the timing in the kernel, or better yet using a realtime kernel - but it is a lot of effort for marginal results when the real issue is that the wrong platform has been chosen.

Theorectically, if you wanted to do it in the simplest way anyway you could use another`if` checking the other photogate input, or better yet use something blocking on a read of the interrupt node for that gpio, and hope that this results in the scheduler waking you up as quickly as possible.  But it will only approximate the timing.

If you want to build a good photogate timer, use a barebones microcontroller and/or feed your inputs directly into a counter timer block's capture trigger.  This could potentially be a $1 class part accessorizing the pi, if you really need the capabilities of that for other purposes.  (Or to put it in hobbyist language, this is properly an Arduino problem not a pi problem, but you could potentially use a baby Arduino to accomplish it and report the time difference to a pi).

Comment: Could explain your comment's third paragraph with theoretical stuff. Also, which parts would I need on top of what I have given here to build a microcontroller photogate that measures accurately but at the same time gives value to pi.  Is it possible to just build something with what I have. But at the same time, I am willing to work harder to build a better photogate so do you know how I can find details on how to build it. Thanks

Comment: Also what is the accuracy of my current photo gate. Thanks